# On determining the plane curves on which the length of the segment of the normal lines between the curve and the x axis are constant

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

So, if $\alpha(t)$ is such a curve, then $g(r) = \alpha(t) + rn(t)$ is the normal line and $w(s) = \alpha(t) + s\alpha'(t)$ is the tangent line, where $n(t)$ is the orthogonal vector to $\alpha'(t)$. Let $P(x_0, y_0)$ be the point where the normal line intersects the $x$ axis and $Q = (x_0, y_0)$ be the vector from the origin to $P$, then I need to find the length of $\alpha(t) - Q$. I tried using coordinates, but as it usually happens, things got very messy. I would appreciate some help with finding an easier start point.

Comment: So $P(x_0,0)$ and what’s the difference between $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: There isn't really a difference. It's just that I've been used to making the distinction between points and vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: Assume the original curve $\alpha$ is arclength parametrized and consider the equation
$$\big(\alpha(s)+\lambda(s)n(s)\big)\cdot (0,1) = 0.$$
What are you assuming about $\lambda(s)$? And what do you always do in differential geometry when you have an equation like this? :)

I'm not sure this is a very interesting question, but you should find two kinds of curves $\alpha$ for which this works.

Comment: In case the OP asked for constant subnormal, parabolae would be first choice.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe: I don't even know what that means!

Comment: A German reference: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnormale

Comment: Oh, that's the distance along the $x$-axis obtained by projecting the normal segment from the point on the curve to the intersection with the $x$-axis. A different question.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm assuming $\lambda(s)$ is a scalar function. Differentiating both sides, I get:

$(\lambda'(s)n(s) + \lambda(s)n'(s) + \alpha'(s))\cdot(0, 1) = 0$

but I can't see how that helps me. Also, I'm not sure of the significance of the equation $(α(s)+λ(s)n(s))\cdot(0,1)=0$ (I'm sure it is relevant to my question, I'm just not seeing how).

Comment: That's the equation that says you pick the scalar multiple $\lambda$ to end up where the normal line intersects the $x$-axis. That the length of that segment is constant says that $\lambda$ is constant. Don't forget Frenet!!

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Using Frenet's equation $-k(s)t(s) = n'(s)$ and the fact that $\lambda$ is constant so it's derivative is $0$, I get $(λ(s)n′(s)+α′(s))\cdot(0,1) = 0$, which leaves me with $(\alpha'(s)(-\lambda(s)k(s) + 1))\cdot(0, 1) = 0$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Regroup to get a product of two real-valued functions is $0$.

Comment: So either $(−λ(s)k(s)+1) = 0$ or $α′(s)\cdot(0, 1) = 0$. I can see that if $α(s) = (x(s), y(s))$, then $y'(s) = 0$, and we have a horizontal line. Alternatively, $(−λ(s)k(s)+1) = 0$, in which case we have $k(s) = \frac{1}{\lambda(s)}$, a constant, so the other possibilty is that $\alpha(s)$ is a circle. Thank you!

Comment: There you go. Of course, if you don't assume a real analytic curve, you could possibly glue different pieces together ... the usual sort of problem with these classification questions in local differential geometry.

Comment: Huh, it didn't occur to me you could glue difference pieces together. That's really interesting, I'll look for more on that.

Comment: For example, you could have a vertical semicircle (centered at the origin), extended by horizontal lines on either end. This curve isn't $C^1$, of course.